# Calling r scripts from web page and displaying report to web page

Tags: shiny, knitr, r-markdown

Friends

Sorry for a general question, but I'm lost in the various discussion threads and was hoping for a pointer to the appropriate documentation:

I have a php/webinterface to a database created with [rackforms](https://www.rackforms.com/) and MySQL. I've successfully embedded r-analytics in this site and can generate tables and graphs but am having trouble displaying the tables and graphs in the web interface. I found shiny/knitr and figured out how to generate a nice summary page using shiny/knitr/rmarkdown and get the html output. But I can't find any instructions on how to call and display this from the data website I created! I'd like to call an r-script that runs a .Rmd script (or similar) and then display the generated tables and plots on the interface. Alternatively, I could link to a page in .html, but the display needs to run the analysis each time its called since the data is live.

I'm sure there must be some description on how to do this somewhere, but I can't find anything that quite gets you all the way. Any pointers out there? I'd appreciate it.

Cheers

Jon

Comment: Well, partial answer here:

Comment: Well, partial answer here: 1) Run a shiny-server (only on *nix, not windows or osx!) 2) set document root in the config file and corresponding web directory (only ONE .Rmd file in a directory, so create subdriectories within the root dir for each rmarkdown file you may have), access the .Rmd by http://ip.ad.re.ss:port/root/sub/*.Rmd.  still trying to figure out how to call this link from a php form that gathers the data into MySQL. (the .Rmd file must obviously call MySQL to retrieve data. Also, if you live in https/or have a firewall, you must allow tcp traffic across it).